# Generating groups of numbers next to each other

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, numbers, grouping

I'm seraching for an algorithm to solve the following problem:

I have a set of Numbers

```
(e.g 100,74,104,76,29,79,98,33,201)
```

and I want to group the Numbers that are next to each other (differ by x)

For example x=10 should output:

```
[(100,104,98) (74,76,79) (33,29) (201)]
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do it.

Edit: I have a lot of starting ideas. The algorithm doesn't have to be efficient, just working is okay.

One of them is:

```
- A) Picking first number, comparing its size with all the other numbers
- B) If the condition is complied, saving it in another set and deleting it from the input set
- C) Select the next element that isn't deleted and Start at A (Proceed until input set is empty)
```

What do you think?

Comment: without any code, or any specific programming language, you're not going to get any help.

Comment: I want to use PHP. If i had some code to show I would post it, but currently I'm trying to work out an algorithm without thinking about an certain implementation.

Comment: well, at least show some effort... what have you thought of so far? what were your ideas? have you come up with some kind of idea for the algorithm?

Comment: An obvious way would be to sort the list and then take as many numbers as you can (ie. until the adding the current one would be further than `x` away from the first one). This would be `O(n log n)`, which is probably overkill, though.

Comment: The algorithm you proposed runs in `O(n^2)`, which is even worse.

Comment: Thanks Alex!
@Doorknob: I edited my initial post with a first idea.

Comment: You could consider using buckets, e.g. for each multiple of the diff, you could have a bucket. then each number gets placed in the bucket that is closest to it. (e.g. 100, 104 & 98 would go in bucket 100 in your example, while 76 & 79 would go in bucket 70). 
Then for each number, it could be grouped with the numbers in its bucket as well as possibly the numbers in the two adjacent buckets.

Comment: @AlexReinking Ack! I just saw this.  Anyway, I'm pretty sure that this is the most efficient approach, unless the numbers are restricted somehow to a specific (small) integer range.

Comment: @robertking Hmm, I do think that this could be faster for a lot of cases (depends on the ratio between (x) and the range of possible values of the numbers in the list).  Its a bit more complicated than the sort-and-scan approach though.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Ideally you would have a hash table so buckets are only created as needed. (so you would have a maximum of N buckets).

Comment: Hash the numbers into buckets of size x and then compare each bucket with adjacent buckets to see if larger groups can be formed. i.e. define hash(num, x) as a function that returns num / x (integer division). It should be close to O(2n) time complexity. You can store the max and mins of each bucket.

Comment: @user2966689 Great! I have retracted my close vote.

Comment: What if a number `A` is close to `B` and `B` is close to `C`, but `A` is not close to `C`? for example, `X=1 A=1 B=2 C=3`? Are they all in the same group? is `{A, B} {C}` and `{A} {B, C}` both legit?

Comment: @robertking Ahh, right.

Comment: @user2966689 I just posted a PHP implementation of the algorithm I proposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my first shot (from the comments). I'll edit this post as I get better ideas.

Algorithm:

```
Input (a) a list L (b) a number x, the maximum gap
1) Sort the list
2) Take as many elements from the list as you can without exceeding the gap
3) Create a new group
4) If there are no more elements in the list, you're done, otherwise to to step 2.
```

Example:

```
Input:  L = [100,74,104,76,29,79,98,33,201], x = 10
Sorted: [29, 33, 74, 76, 79, 98, 100, 104, 201]
Output: [[29, 33], [74, 76, 79], [98, 100, 104], [201]]
```

Since I noticed you were using PHP, here's an implementation in PHP:

```
function cluster($arr, $x)
{
        $clusters = array();
        if(count($arr) == 0)
                return $clusters;

        sort($arr);
        $curCluster[0] = array_shift($arr);
        while(count($arr) > 0) {
                $cur = array_shift($arr);
                if($cur - $curCluster[0] < $x)
                        array_push($curCluster, $cur);
                else {
                        array_push($clusters, $curCluster);
                        $curCluster = array($cur);
                }
        }
        if(count($curCluster) != 0)
                array_push($clusters, $curCluster);
        return $clusters;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your work! Unfortunatelly as i tried to use it the above example results in:
[29, 29, 33], [74, 76, 79], [98, 100, 104], [201]
(29 is duplicated)

Comment: You're totally right! I'm sorry. It's a one-line bug. I'll fix it quick :)

Comment: Done! and I just tested it!